# Why can't I see HTML 5 <dialog>?

Tags: html, jsf, facelets

Here is my Facelets file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    Place your content here!
    <dialog>
        <dt>Sam</dt>
        <dd>Knock, Knock.</dd>
        <dt>Eric</dt>
        <dd>Who's there?</dd>
        <dt>Sam</dt>
        <dd>Justin.</dd>
        <dt>Eric</dt>
        <dd>Justin who?</dd>
        <dt>Sam</dt>
        <dd>Justin time for dinner!</dd>
    </dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

What I see in the browser is only

> Place your content here!

When I check the source for this file, I see in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title></head><body>
Place your content here!
<dialog>
    <dt>Sam</dt>
    <dd>Knock, Knock.</dd>
    <dt>Eric</dt>
    <dd>Who's there?</dd>
    <dt>Sam</dt>
    <dd>Justin.</dd>
    <dt>Eric</dt>
    <dd>Justin who?</dd>
    <dt>Sam</dt>
    <dd>Justin time for dinner!</dd>
</dialog>
<ul id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages" title="Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages"></ul></body>
</html>
```

So, from the source code, it looks like it should be a valid html5 file? But currently, I can't see the content that should be in the dialog tag?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @TimBJames Chrome, the latest version. I also copied this source to a .html file and opened, still no difference. I can see HTML5 content online.

Comment: seems like `h:body` is not rendering as there is no `<body>` tags in HTML

Comment: @amphibient <body> is right after </head>

Comment: Whilst the `<dialog>` element was once defined for that use in HTML5, that was a few years ago. More recently it is now defined as "The dialog element represents a part of an application that a user interacts with to perform a task, for example a dialog box, inspector, or window.", so you should not use it to mark up a chat in the way you currently are.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks, I actually just picked some random HTML5 only tag to see if it works. Turns that it was a bad choice!

Comment: @Alochi is right. Before, I believe, `dialog` was supposed to be used to mark up conversations ('dialogs'), but that tag was abandoned. Then a completely new tag was invented, albeit with the same name. The new `dialog` tag is used to host a dialog box in a web application. It is hidden by default; the boolean attribute `open` is used to display it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have never used the `dialog` tab before, but after inspecting the DOM and styles built into Chrome, it seems as though by default the element is set to `display: none;`

```
dialog:not([open]){ display: none; }
```

So to display this on your page, you will need to set the style;

```
dialog{ display: block; }
```

**Update**

Also, you can use the `open` attribute on the `dialog` element

```
<dialog open>....</dialog>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It worked. However when I try <dialog open> I get this error: Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 13] Attribute name "open" associated with an element type "dialog" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Also, dialog{ display: block; } does not work. I need to assign a class to it, and say <dialog class=myClass>, then apply the style on the class.

Comment: Sorry false information. dialog{display: block;} works, only IntelliJ complains about it. The browser is fine with it.

Comment: Yeah you can add the `display` style through a class also. Or I would presume it would be `open="open"`

Comment: The dialog element is documented at http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element

Comment: -1 for not explaining what the tag means, and giving a bad solution before the 'right' one.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for your comment. Personally I don't think it deserved a -1 as it helped Koray Tugay with their specific problem. Their specific problem was not "What does the `<dialog />` tag mean. Nor would I consider either of my answers as being "bad".

Comment: @Tim: Let's agree to disagree. Since *semantics* is so important in HTML (especially HTML  5), using elements, or talking about how they are to be used, without knowing whay they represent feels very wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `open` attribute on the `dialog` element

```
<dialog open>....</dialog>
```

By default the element is set to `display: none;`

```
dialog:not([open]){ display: none; }
```

Also note, this feature is not available in all browsers at this time. E.g. in Chrome it requires chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features to be enabled.

(This is a heavily edited version of Tim B James answer).