# Angular Material Dialog hiding elements

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, angular-material

I want to make a confirm dialog in a node.js Angular project, which seems pretty straightforward. I'm using Material styling, for faster delvelopment.

When running the project, the opened dialog is empty:

[image: Empty Dialog problem]

The dialog component `dialog.component.ts` is somewhat flexible, and looks like this:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  cancelButton: string;
  acceptButton: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.scss']
})

export class DialogComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData
  ) {}

  onNoClick() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

The component opening the dialog looks like this (some unnecessary parts are cut out):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { QuestUpdate } from 'src/app/enums/questUpdate';
import { Constant } from 'src/app/interfaces/constant';
import { Quest } from 'src/app/interfaces/quest';
import { User } from 'src/app/interfaces/user';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';
import { ConstantService } from 'src/app/services/constant.service';
import { QuestService } from 'src/app/services/quest.service';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AbstractComponent } from '../abstract.component';
import { DialogComponent, DialogData } from '../common/dialog/dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent extends AbstractComponent implements OnInit {

  loading = true;
  user: User;
  quests: Quest[] = [];
  xpNeeded: number;

  constructor(protected authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
              protected userService: UserService,
              protected constantService: ConstantService,
              public router: Router,
              protected questService: QuestService,
              public dialog: MatDialog) {
    super(authenticationService, userService, constantService, router);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // ...
  }

  getQuestListForUser(id: number) {
    // ...
  }

  getXPNeeded() {
    // ...
  }

  updateQuest(questUpdate: {questId: number, update: QuestUpdate}) {
    // can call openConfirmFinishDialog
  }

  openConfirmFinishDialog(quest: Quest) {
    const data: DialogData = {
      title: 'Confirm completion',
      text: 'Finish quest?',
      cancelButton: 'No',
      acceptButton: 'Yes'
    };
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { data });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      // Do stuff after closing
    });
  }
}
```

The DialogComponent is both declared and added as entryComponent in my `component.module.ts`-file, which is routed to from `app.module.ts`. I have also tried adding it directly in the latter file instead, but nothing changed.
I have also added `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'` to `styles.scss`.

I noticed in the console that the element containing the dialog actually holds all the needed elements, but is hiding them, and they are not styled when displayed manually:

[image: Element hiding Dialog]

Even though I got all these clues to my problem, I cannot see what I did wrong. I used a lot of time researching before I came here.

Comment: did you got any error in console

Comment: No errors in the console, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your component selector to anything besides `dialog`. Chrome now has built in styles for a `dialog` element that is hiding your dialog content.

Reference: [Why can't I see HTML 5 <dialog>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487785/why-cant-i-see-html-5-dialog)